# HTTP response getting html response

Tags: java, android, json, url, web

response getting from server is html response. How can i know whether the reponse is correct? how can i check that in server?

Comment: does the site give you a json o/p in browser thats ur api url as u call it

Comment: No i'm getting html response..

Comment: echo json_encode(array('name'=>$data)); use this php code to respond with a json data in a partic url replace name and data wit ur corresponding values and check url for a json o/p or use rest/soap service

Comment: what value should i give in place of name and data?

Comment: name is the name you want for the array and data is the php data you want to convert to json see an example http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json

Comment: for twitter site this is the url they had given, http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=,   For my site what should i give??

Comment: that you have to decide it all depends use rest service or soap service if you want a session and all thats better but to start with you can use direct json op

Comment: This is my response when i run the app and the emulator is displaying like this..http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/831/response.png/

Comment: this is an xml file use json alone (as you are using json parsing) it should give an o/p in json format or else there is a problem in your server code

Answer (score 0):

These api urls corresponds to a REST web service and thats why when you call those urls, you are getting data. So you need to create your own REST service api for your site to fetch data first.

For creating dot net based REST Service, Use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide) link. For creating Java based REST service, follow [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html) link.